# choice of sentence with operating / to operate

Tags: grammar

Which sentence is better:

- Ranking students in a random way does not value the work done.
- To rank students in a random way does not value the work done.

Comment: neither sentence makes sense; what are you trying to say? "operating" can not value anything, it isn't capable of doing anything.

Comment: I think the OP means that the act of "operating in a random way" is what doesn't value something, but I agree that neither sentence is clear and we need more context.

Comment: Instead of operate I can say "ranking students", better? I will edit

Comment: Both are grammatical. "ranking students" is ambiguous (it could mean "students who rank") but still seems more natural to me (native UK English speaker).